# Non-null many-to-zero-or-one relationship in EF code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a classic one-to-many relationship except there's no "one" for every item on the "many" side. Here are my tables:

**SESSIONS:**

```
ID        IP
1         1.1.1.1
2         2.2.2.2
```

**USERS:**

```
IP        NAME
1.1.1.1   John
```

...generated from the following POCO's:

```
public class Session {
    public int     id   { get; set; }
    public long    ip   { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    [Key]
    public long    ip   { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Session> sessions { get; set; }
}
```

**Some** sessions have a corresponding user (by IP). I'd like to retain the IP even if there is no associated user, and to be able to navigate User.sessions.

With the POCO's above, EF will understandably generate a FK from `Session.ip` to `User.ip`, preventing me from inserting Sessions with an IP that is not correlated to a user. Making `Session.ip` nullable allows me to insert sessions not related to a user, but then I lose the IP (it must be null).

Is there any way to achieve this?

A million thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the POCO classes like this:

```
 public class Session
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public long ip { get; set; }      
    public User User {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public long ip { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Session> sessions { get; set; }
}
```

this will Create a Nullable User_id field on the Session Table and should give you the desired results. Please note that this has removed ip as the PK on the User table and changed it to a generic integer id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this workaround too but was wondering if there's a fundamental solution to the problem. My Sessions table is large (1+ gb of new data per day) and I don't want to store unnecessary columns and try avoiding nullables for performance reasons.

Comment: have you tried overriding OnModelCreating in you dbContext... I think you could remove the foreign Key ( modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.sessions).WithOptional())
           
        }

Comment: No, that has the same effect as defining Session.ip as nullable, i.e. it generates a FK that must either be null or point to a valid User, but cannot point to a non-existing user.

Comment: This problem doesn't have any other solution except completely removing FK and enforcing the constraint in your application.